# Convert text output to data frame [R]

Tags: r

I have a text output that returns

```
[1] "Dynamic Columns\tMeasure Names\tDynamic Demographics Title\tFirst COVID-19 Dose Administered\tMeasure Values\tVax Complete\r\nAmerican Indian or Alaska Native\tCompleted\tRace\t2856\t0.042746728\t1532\r\nAmerican Indian or Alaska Native\tInitiated\tRace\t2856\t0.079689723\t1532\r\nAsian\tCompleted\tRace\t36975\t0.130168327\t17353\r\nAsian\tInitiated\tRace\t36975\t0.277356877\t17353\r\nBlack or African-American\tCompleted\tRace\t110031\t0.091539309\t66419\r\nBlack or African-American\tInitiated\tRace\t110031\t0.151645789\t66419\r\nMulti-racial\tCompleted\tRace\t91322\t0.507244993\t74389\r\nMulti-racial\tInitiated\tRace\t91322\t0.622708025\t74389\r\nNative Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander\tCompleted\tRace\t3506\t0.234959927\t2316\r\nNative Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander\tInitiated\tRace\t3506\t0.355686314\t2316\r\nWhite\tCompleted\tRace\t1267155\t0.161650926\t822187\r\nWhite\tInitiated\tRace\t1267155\t0.249136485\t822187\r\n"
```

and I'm wondering if this can be converted into a data frame, or downloaded as a csv file?

Comment: Perhaps you could share the data source if you'd like us to suggest how to download it. Failing that, how about some of the code that you used to return the value? Also, please provide a sample of your expected output.

Comment: `read.table(text="..", sep="\t", header=TRUE)` worked for me.